# Stocking different types of data into an 2D numpy array

Tags: python, dataframe, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn

I would like to know how I can store different data into a numpy array, in order to feed it to a machine Learning SVC algorithm.
My goal, is to get a **dataframe of size (sample * features)** like this:

[image: Data frame schema]

With:

- Feature 1 in gray containing **list of size n**
- Feature 2 in red, containing **2D numpy array** of shape (i,k)
- Feature ... **Something else (array for pwelch spectrum, integers, float, ...)**
- Feature n in blue, containing **integer**.

**How can I do that in Python ? Is this going to be ok for sklearn ?**

Here is the current error from the code bellow:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------- Imports --------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import io as sio
from scipy import signal

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

"""----------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------ Parameters -------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

# Path to the clean EEG .mat files
EEG_path = "data"   

# Listing of the .mat files
EEG = list()
for elt in os.listdir(EEG_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(EEG_path, elt)):
        if '.mat' in elt[len(elt)-4:]:
            EEG.append(elt)

# Spectrum used
spectrum = ['all', (1,45), (8,12)]

nb_features = 3

"""----------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------ Functions --------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

# Function on 1 channel
# Input: All points from one channel, for one epoch
def filter(x, n, fs, fc1, fc2):
    b, a = signal.butter(n, [fc1/(fs/2), fc2/(fs/2)], 'bandpass')
    y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, x)
    return y

def haming(x, L):
    # Symetric L-points hamming window
    window = signal.hamming(L)
    y = x * window.T                            # Element wise multiplication
    return y

# Function on one epoch
# Input is a matrix of size (channel * length)
def amp_mean(x):
    size = x.shape
    y = list()
    for i in range(size[0]):
        y.append(np.mean(x[i,:]))
    return y

def amp_max(x):
    size = x.shape
    y = list()
    for i in range(size[0]):
        y.append(np.max(abs(x[i,:])))
    return y

"""----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------- Script ---------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

# Load data          
s_EEG = "{}/{}".format(EEG_path, EEG[4])
data = sio.loadmat(s_EEG)['s_EEG']['data'][0][0].astype(float)     # data[i, j ,k]
labels = sio.loadmat(s_EEG)['s_EEG']['labels'][0][0][0]            # labels[k]
fs = sio.loadmat(s_EEG)['s_EEG']['sampling_rate'][0][0][0][0]      # 500 Hz
size = data.shape

# Creates an empty data frame of size (epoch * features)
df = np.empty(shape = (size[2], nb_features * len(spectrum)))

# Filling the dataframe with features
# for every epoch
for k in range(size[2]):
    for freq in spectrum:
        data_to_compute = np.empty(shape = size, dtype = float)

        # Apply hamming
        if freq == 'all':
            for i in range(size[0]):
                data_to_compute[i,:,k] = haming(data[i,:,k], size[1])

        # Apply hamming after filtering
        else:
            for i in range(size[0]):
                data_to_compute[i,:,k] = haming(filter(data[i,:,k], 
                               15, fs, freq[0], freq[1]), size[1])

        # data_to_compute is ready to have feature extracted

        for n in range(0, df.shape[1], nb_features):
            df[k, n] = data_to_compute[:,:,k]
            df[k, n+1] = amp_mean(data_to_compute[:,:,k])
            df[k, n+2] = amp_max(data_to_compute[:,:,k])

# X signal / Y label
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data, 
                                                    list(labels), 
                                                    test_size=0.15, 
                                                    random_state=42)

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Variable type:

[image: Variables types]

Thanks !

Comment: No it's not going to be okay. This is not compatible with the underlying mathematical theory of those algorithms nor sklearn. Read sklearn's excellent documentation (the best i know) on what's expected input.

Comment: Ok so from what I understand, the data must be C-ordered contiguous. Does that mean that for a signal, let's say with 100 points, I have to feed sklearn with an array X of the 100 points, one after the one before ? What if I want to add the pwlech signal (let's say 100 points again) ? Do I simply add the points after the precedent feature, and get an array of size 200 ?

Comment: ```(n_samples, n_features)```. That's an 2d-array (if it's C or Fortran-ordered internally does not matter; at least for the API, might be changed automatically). The first row is sample 0, the second row is sample 1. So the core-concept is: each sample is a 1d-vector of floats. Whatever you want to do, you need to process your data to achieve this. sklearn's preprocessing docs talk about this a lot!

Comment: That's clear, but my samples are like that 19*1000. 19 different signals of length 1000 for every sample. How do you process that into a 1D vector of float ? Is it ok to do SKLearn on discrete signals ? Or can you only use it with features like avg, max, min, ... values ! Like for instance on finance, when you use only values and not signals... That's the point I don't get. Can I use it with signals ?

Comment: 1d-vector of floats only! What's unclear about that? How you map your signals to this has nothing to do with sklearn. That's feature-processing and is model/task-dependent.

Comment: Ok but then, is it ok to place let's say the raw signal (so 19*1000 reshaped into 19000 1D) followed by a single value, let's say the mean, and then by the pwelch signal (19000 1D again) ? It feels weird to treat the signal like that.

Comment: It probably is. But that's the core-problem of nearly all ML-tasks. This depends on the task and the underlying algorithm. This question is not suited for SO.

Comment: Ok. 2 more questions come to mind then. 1. What does SO stands for ? 2. Do you know any ML algorithm that is suited for signals ? or suited for both signals and single values ?

Comment: SO = StackOverflow which is mostly about programming and less about special-areas like mathematical-modelling or ML-preprocessing. Now you ask for an ML-algorithm while the dicussion before was about feature-preprocessing. Have a look at some basic ML introduction to get an idea about the core-concepts and assumptions. A signal is also probably bound to different interpretations and people will use different approaches for different kind of signals (monotone, periodic; smooth or not; i'm only scratching the surface; not my area).